# Can the Godox XPro work with strobes from Elinchrom

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, godox, elinchrom

I am planning on visiting a studio that is equipped with Elinchrom D-Lite One RX heads and I was wondering if the Godox XPro transmitter (Sony) that I current own is able to fire them off (manual mode)? I don't seem to be able to find a definitive answer on Godox or Elinchrom.

Comment: Doesn't the studio have a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You would need at least one Godox receiver (e.g. X1R) for one of the heads, and then the other heads could be put into optical slave mode. Everything will be manual only (no TTL, wireless power adjustments, etc).